# Using boost interval_map

Tags: c++, boost

Trying to follow the `boost_party` example of interval_map I made this example code:

```
#include "boost/icl/interval.hpp"
#include "boost/icl/interval_map.hpp"
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef std::set<string> ids;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ids ids1;   
    ids1.insert("T1");
    ids ids2;
    ids2.insert("T2");
    boost::icl::interval_map<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, ids> mymap;
    boost::icl::closed_interval<int> i1 = boost::icl::closed_interval<int>(2, 7);
    boost::icl::closed_interval<int> i2 = boost::icl::closed_interval<int>(3, 8);
    mymap += make_pair(i1, ids1);
    mymap += make_pair(i2, ids2);
    return 0;
}
```

But this get's this compilation error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘boost::icl::interval_map<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >’ and ‘std::pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >’)
  mymap += make_pair(i1, ids1);
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

should most likely be `mymap.insert(make_pair(...));` instead of `mymap += make_pair(...);`. That's the syntax for `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: I changed it to mymap.insert(make_pair(...)) but now I get this error:  call of overloaded ‘insert(std::pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >)’ is ambiguous
  mymap.insert(make_pair(i1, ids1));

Comment: then make your types clear : `mymap.insert(std::pair<int, ids>(i1,ids1)); mymap.insert(std::pair<int, ids>(i2, ids2));`

Comment: might force you to use `boost::pair` actually instead of `std::pair`

Comment: As far as I understand boost only has a compressed_pair struct. But, mymap.insert(boost::compressed_pair<closed_interval<int>, ids>(i1,ids1)); gives me this error: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::icl::interval_map<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >::insert(boost::compressed_pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >)’
  mymap.insert(boost::compressed_pair<closed_interval<int>, ids>(i1,ids1));

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp looks to be using std::pair

Comment: With std::pair: mymap.insert(std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1)); I then get this error: call of overloaded ‘insert(std::pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<long int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >)’ is ambiguous
  mymap.insert(std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1));

Comment: how about `mymap.interval_base_map::insert(std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1));` to resolve inherited function ambiguity

Comment: Same error: call of overloaded ‘insert(std::pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<long int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >)’ is ambiguous
  mymap.interval_base_map::insert(std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1));

Comment: k should be `boost::icl::insert(&mymap, std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1))` I believe

Comment: Unfortunately not: no matching function for call to ‘insert(boost::icl::interval_map<boost::icl::closed_interval<long int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >*, std::pair<boost::icl::closed_interval<long int>, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >)’
  insert(&mymap, std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1));

Comment: how about `const mymap::element_type thePair(std::pair<closed_interval<long>, ids>(i1,ids1)); mymap.insert(thePair);`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is in your declaration of the interval_map:

```
 boost::icl::interval_map<boost::icl::closed_interval<int>, ids> mymap;
```

The problem is, that the library automatically wants to create intervals of the first type you give it. So in your case the key of map is interval of interval of integers.
So in your case all you need to do is to use:

```
boost::icl::interval_map<int, ids> mymap;
```

In that case your map will be mapping **int intervals** onto sets of strings.

Comment: To complement your answer, if OP wants the map to store intervals as `closed_interval`, then it needs to provide the full list of template parameters: `icl::interval_map<int, ids, icl::partial_absorber, std::less, icl::plus, icl::inter_section, closed_interval<unsigned, std::less>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am a little late, but this compiles:

```
#include "boost/icl/interval.hpp"
#include "boost/icl/interval_map.hpp"
#include <set>
using namespace std;

typedef std::set<string> ids;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ids ids1;   
    ids1.insert("T1");
    ids ids2;
    ids2.insert("T2");
    boost::icl::interval_map<int, ids> mymap;
    auto i1 = boost::icl::interval<int>::closed(2, 7);
    auto i2 = boost::icl::interval<int>::closed(3, 8);
    mymap += make_pair(i1, ids1);
    mymap += make_pair(i2, ids2);
    return 0;
}
```

You would have to check, if this matches your intended semantics, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `+=` by `.insert(...)`. (I never understood well when to use `+=` or `insert`, I use `insert` always).

Second, I think the key for the `interval_map` is `int` and not `discrete_interval<int>`. Also, I don't think is up to you whether the intervals are closed or (semi)open. With `discrete` intervals unions of open intervals can be become closed intervals. So let the dynamic type system choose for you. The code ends up looking like this (C++98, compiles with `g++ 4.8.3`)

```
typedef std::set<std::string> ids;

ids ids1;   
ids1.insert("T1");
ids ids2;
ids2.insert("T2");
boost::icl::interval_map<int, ids> mymap;
boost::icl::discrete_interval<int> i1 = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(2, 7);
boost::icl::discrete_interval<int> i2 = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(3, 8);
mymap.insert(make_pair(i1, ids1));
mymap.insert(make_pair(i2, ids2));
```

Curiosity: your code compiles in with `-std=c++11`, I don't know if it does the right thing though.